# Wordpress Premium Theme download

Tags: premium

I want to use the theme in the http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/organization/

But I don't want to use it with a wordpress.com blog. This is a premium theme and I would like purchase, download and use it on my own domain.

But I can't find a download link. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress com does not sell their selection of premium themes for self hosted use. However such themes are often copies or tweaked versions of generic commercial themes from development shops.

You can see in sidebar that the theme in question was developed by Organic Themes. According to their own site it is [exclusive to wp com but they have similar earlier theme](http://www.organicthemes.com/wordpress-com-organization-theme/) available for sale.

Comment: Beat me by 48 seconds =/

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for `"organic themes" organization` returns this in the first result:

The Organization theme is our NonProfit Theme, re-purposed for the WordPress.com community. (...) **Note: The WordPress.com version of Organization is separate from the NonProfit Theme offered on our site, and only for use on the WordPress.com blogging community. It is not to be confused with the open source version of WordPress from wordpress.org. The wordpress.com version can not be used on a self-hosted WordPress site.**

***Please purchase the NonProfit Theme from our website for use on a self-hosted WordPress site.***

([source](http://www.organicthemes.com/wordpress-com-organization-theme/))